Sqlite-jdbc mmap_size does not persist
I'm using xerial sqlite-jdbc library. When setting the mmap_size, I used the following
try (PreparedStatement pstmt =
   conn.prepareStatement(
   "pragma mmap_size=1000")) {
   pstmt.execute();
}

However, this setting does not seem to persist when new connection is opened for the same database, though sqlite documentation says " The mmap_size applies separately to each database file".
What did I miss?
Also, if mmap_size is not for the database, does that mean mmap is only usefull if I keep one connection open to execute all the queries?

Like many other pragmas, you have to set it each time you open a database.
